# JSON_EXTRACT in Array

Tags: mariadb, json

I have a column with data in json and I need to get the value of an attribute.
I need to extract the value_name where the id = SELLER_SKU

JSON_UNQUOTE( JSON_EXTRACT( i.json, '$.value_name' ))

```
{
    "attributes": [{
            "id": "BRAND",
            "name": "Marca",
            "value_id": "3807598",
            "value_name": "Arbel",
            "value_struct": null,
            "values": [{
                    "id": "3807598",
                    "name": "Arbel",
                    "struct": null
                }
            ],
            "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
            "attribute_group_name": "Outros"
        }, {
            "id": "SELLER_SKU",
            "name": "SKU",
            "value_id": null,
            "value_name": "00004-1",
            "value_struct": null,
            "values": [{
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "00004-1",
                    "struct": null
                }
            ],
            "attribute_group_id": "OTHERS",
            "attribute_group_name": "Outros"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If the data is that regular, you should store it in columns in tables, not JSON.

Comment: in my case it is not necessary to store in a table I rarely use them, and the json structure is huge, this is only part of the json

Comment: Do you necessarily need to extract the value using the database?  That is, instead of doing it in the app?